# Compile TypeScript parameter types to JS type check?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to compile *TypeScript* parameter type to type checking `if`-statements to prevent runtime errors like this:

```
// TypeScript file
function test(param: string) {
    return param.toUpperCase();
}

// should become JavaScript file
function test(param) {
    if (typeof param !== "string") {
        throw new Error("param must be of type 'string'");
    }
    return param.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question. I am aware of the fact that types are stripped by the TSC. So my question is, if there is a way to add some kind of native JS type check right before types are being stripped.

Comment: AFAIK by default there is no way to auto add such native JS checks